# Can we use "too to" together in a sentence?

Tags: grammar

Like in this sentence:

> 'I don’t want to lose this double murder case too to them.'

Or do I need to use a comma?

> 'I don’t want to lose this double murder case too, to them.'

Comment: Both sentences are grammatically correct, but sound awkward. A better alternative is: "I don't want to lose this double murder case to them, as well."

Comment: I would strongly advise rewording to avoid the "too to" sequence, even if it is technically "legal".  You can reorder, use "as well" rather than "too", and several other options.

Comment: yes I think as well, can serve the purpose as pointed by V0ight and Hot Licks.

Comment: "Today's event goes until two o'clock.  Tomorrow's goes to two too."

Comment: @Hellion - Actually, since it's two days in a row, that's "to two twain".

Answer (score 2):

> I don’t want to lose this double murder case too to them.

The preposition phrase *to them* is a complement of the verb *LOSE* here. Because of this it is best to put this phrase right after the verb. In contrast the adverb *too* is functioning as an adjunct. It is best placed at the end of the verb phrase after any complements.

> I don’t want to lose this double murder case to them too.

It is the fact that these phrases are in the wrong order which makes the sentence seem a bit odd. Having *too* and *to* next to each other is a bit of a red herring.

Comment: Part of the awkwardness of "to them too" is that it sounds exactly the same as "to them two", which is a colloquial way of saying "to those two", referring to two people.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Yes, a bit, but they'll be disambiguated by the stress and intonation. I.e. *to them two* will have the tonic syllable (the main stress f you like) on the word *them* and the word *two* is likely be said at a low pitch coming in the tail of the sentence. In contrast in *them too*, the tonic syllable will be on the word *too*, which all other things being equal will be said at a high falling pitch (or a fall-rise). So they won't in actual fact sound the same.

Comment: that might often be the case, yes, but I wouldn't say that it's guaranteed to happen in all cases for all speakers.